# I am getting an error when I am trying to build my Docker Postgres image

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have a requirement to build a custom docker image of a PostgreSQL database that is `postGIS` enabled. Now there is this is an already existing image that [does this here](https://hub.docker.com/r/mdillon/postgis/~/dockerfile/); however, this is an assignment given to me and so I have to make my own Docker file and image.

What I tried is as follows:

```
mkdir postgres
cd postgres
touch Dockerfile
```

Now I edit the Dockerfile and edited it look as follows:

```
FROM postgres:9.4
MAINTAINER Mike Dillon <mike@appropriate.io>

ENV POSTGIS_MAJOR 2.1

ENV POSTGIS_VERSION 2.1.7+dfsg-3~94.git954a8d0.pgdg80+1

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \ postgresql-$PG_MAJOR-postgis-$POSTGIS_MAJOR=$POSTGIS_VERSION \ postgis=$POST$

RUN mkdir -p /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

COPY ./initdb-postgis.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/postgis.sh

# Optional: Drop database

RUN dropdb -U postgres pgrouting-workshop

# Create a new routing database
16
RUN createdb -U postgres pgrouting-workshop
RUN psql -U user -d pgrouting-workshop -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis;"
RUN psql -U user -d pgrouting-workshop -c "CREATE EXTENSION pgrouting;"
```

The Dockerfile [can be viewed here](http://chopapp.com/#a3nl3ktj) too.

Basically the Dockerfile is the same as the [mdillon/postgis](https://hub.docker.com/r/mdillon/postgis/~/dockerfile/) image.

Now when I run the build command as follows:

```
docker build -t gautam/postgresql:v1 .
```

I get the following error:

```
E: Unable to locate package  postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.1

E: Couldn't find any package by regex ' postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.1'
E: Unable to locate package  postgis
E: Unable to locate package  
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \ postgresql-$PG_MAJOR-postgis-$POSTGIS_MAJOR=$POSTGIS_VERSION \ postgis=$POSTGIS_VERSION \ && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

because you should either remove slashes or do cr/lf after them.

```
#good 
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends  postgresql-$PG_MAJOR-postgis-$POSTGIS_MAJOR=$POSTGIS_VERSION postgis=$POST$
#good 
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    postgresql-$PG_MAJOR-postgis-$POSTGIS_MAJOR=$POSTGIS_VERSION \
    postgis=$POST$
#bad
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \ postgresql-$PG_MAJOR-postgis-$POSTGIS_MAJOR=$POSTGIS_VERSION \ postgis=$POST$
```

Comment: @Mykolagurow , now i get an error `Unknown instruction: POSTGRESQL-$PG_MAJOR-POSTGIS-$POSTGIS_MAJOR=$POSTGIS_VERSION
` , my docker file looks like this http://chopapp.com/#yhgzfw54

Comment: Alexander, your links do not work. I guess you can do the comparison with the example you have provided yourself, which is working. Pay attention to the indentations and end of lines.

Comment: The link will load in 2-3 mins , keep the tab open ;)